# Insert multiple rows with one column from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables

```
 CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    name character varying(255),
    CONSTRAINT table1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
 );

 CREATE TABLE table2 (   
     id bigint NOT NULL,
     name character varying(255),
     table1_id bigint,
     CONSTRAINT table2_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id), 
     CONSTRAINT fk_table1_table2 FOREIGN KEY (table1_id) 
     REFERENCES table1 (id) MATCH SIMPLE
 );
```

now what i want to do is for each entry in table1 add entry in table2

ie if my table 1 has entries

```
|id | name   |
|1  | First  | 
|2  | Second | 
|3  | Third  |
```

I need to create three entries in table2

```
insert into table2 (id,name,table2_id) values (nextval('table2_seq'),'new entry', 1);
insert into table2 (id,name,table2_id) values (nextval('table2_seq'),'new entry', 2);
insert into table2 (id,name,table2_id) values (nextval('table2_seq'),'new entry', 3);
```

and as only foreign key is changed for each new entry, i was wonder is it any possibility to automate this process.
Is it possible to achieve with query, or should i look at procedures?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an insert based on a select:

```
insert into table2 (id,name,table1_id)
select nextval('table2_seq'), 'new entry', t1.id
from table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to get a "SELECT ... WHERE" in the subquery, likely not enough coffee, but finalised on the below syntax:

```
insert into table (col1, col2 ...)
select 'staticval1',
r.variable1 from reftable r where r.variable2 = 'Some search term'
...;
```